# How do I dynamically change dynamodb tablename in c# using object persistence model

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I was using dynamodb **Object Persistence model.**

```
DynamoDBTable("mydynamodbtablename")]
public class mytable
{
  ....
}
```

problem is now if I tried to make the name of the table to change dynamically in runtime (I get table names through config files), I get errors

```
var Table_Name = Config.GetTableName();
DynamoDBTable(Table_Name)]
public class mytable
{
  ....
}
```

error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type xxx

Is there a way (easy way) so that I can still use DDB Object Persistence Model and make tables name dynamic?

Update:

It seems that I didn't mentioned ddb persistence model clearly. Here is the official document
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CRUDHighLevelExample1.html

and here is an example of how in real practice do we use object persistence model

```
var records = await context.LoadAsync<mytable>(somekey);
foreach(var item in records)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Use the overload of the `LoadAsync<T>` method that accepts a `DynamoDBOperationConfig`:

```
var config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig 
{ 
    OverrideTableName = "MyTableName"
};
var records = await context.LoadAsync<mytable>(somekey, config);
foreach(var item in records)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it for the whole app(which I guess is the case since you mention config files) you should use the overload of DynamocDBContext which takes a DynamoDBContextConfig. e.g. in dotnet core you would do:

```
services.AddTransient<IDynamoDBContext>(c => new 
DynamoDBContext(c.GetService<IAmazonDynamoDB>(),
                new DynamoDBContextConfig 
                { 
                    TableNamePrefix = Configuration.GetValue("MyEnvironment", "unspecified")  + "-" 
                }));
```

Answer (score 2):

The main classes on Document Model are `Table` and `Document`. The `Table` class has the different APIs to perform the database operations (PutItem, GetItem, DeleteItem)

When you load the table using `LoadTable` API, you can set the `TableConfig` to override the table name values.

```
public Table LoadTable(
         IAmazonDynamoDB ddbClient,
         TableConfig config
)
```

The API accepts the `TableConfig` parameter. The `TableConfig` class has methods to override the table name.

```
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.TableConfig 
TableName
```

**Example:-**

You can set the `tableName` on tableConfig object.

```
// Set up the Table object
var tableConfig = new TableConfig("tableName");
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, tableConfig);
Document document = table.GetItem(101); // Primary key 101.
```

Comment: thanks, but this is Document Model. I understand all the facts that 1) table class definitions are part of Document Model even used by object persistence model. and 2) we can use document model to achieve this. Question, how do I use persistence model? Most of our codes are written with persistence model. thanks!!