# how to dynamically set table name in dynamodb using serverless and DynamoDBContext?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We need to be able to set table name based on build environment. Consider the following class:

```
[DynamoDBTable("movies")]
public class Movie
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey(AttributeName = "Released")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public List<string> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

In `serverless.yml`, can the table name be set like this:

```
functions:
    update-movies:
        environment:
            tableName: movies-prod
```

Then in the code we can load the table name dynamically based on the table name in the tableName variable. We prefer to use `DynamoDBContext` rather than `DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel` (which already has a solution here [How do I dynamically change dynamodb tablename in c# using object persistence model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043148/how-do-i-dynamically-change-dynamodb-tablename-in-c-sharp-using-object-persisten))

Something like this in Java:
https://medium.com/@onclouds/aws-lambda-use-different-dynamodb-tables-for-different-stages-5eda9f5378b2

Comment: Did you actually ask a question? [ask]   Your questions reads as a set of requirements

Comment: yeah, just edit the title to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution by passing a table name prefix:

```
DynamoDBContextConfig config = new DynamoDBContextConfig()
{
    TableNamePrefix = "prod-"
};

_dynamoDBContext = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(), config);
```

You still have to name your table `movies` though:

```
[DynamoDBTable("movies")]
public class Movie
```

`DynamoDBContext` will add the prefix to the table name when loading the context. So it will try to load `prod-movies`, `stag-movies`.

Here is where the table prefix is used in AWS SDK internally

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(flatConfig.TableNamePrefix))
    tableName = flatConfig.TableNamePrefix + tableName;
```

(https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/b691e46e57a3e24477e6a5fa2e849da44db7002f/sdk/src/Services/DynamoDBv2/Custom/DataModel/ContextInternal.cs)

Some references that helped me find the solution:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/enhancements-to-the-dynamodb-sdk/

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/b691e46e57a3e24477e6a5fa2e849da44db7002f/sdk/test/Services/DynamoDBv2/UnitTests/Custom/DynamoDBTests.cs